# How do I add logic to select a connection string when a method is called instead of injecting the connection string into the constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, custom-attributes, action-filter

The question title may be misleading to duplicate but my requirement is different.

My requirement is to initialize a variable before each `method` getting called.

```
//dummy code
Connection con;
public async Task<MyClass> GetDetails(int Id)
{
    con = new Connection("conString");
    //and after that other logic.....
}
```

Problem:

- I can not initialize that `variable` in `constructor` because the `conString` will not be available as it's using `DI` and the `constructor` getting called before, that is in `Startup.cs`.
- I can't go (not sure but assuming) for `ActionFilters` because this class is not my `Controller Class`.
- Or even I go for `Filters` how to initialize that variable as I will be writing `Filter` in a different class and this `variable` will not be present there.
- Or do I need to write the one line of `code` in each method which I am trying to avoid.

Here like something I want but not aware of how to do it.

```
Connection con;
[Filter/Attribute(con)]
public async Task<MyClass> GetDetails(int Id)
{
    //con should have initialized till here.
    //conString I can get where the Logic defined
    //and after that other logic.....
}
```

Any other better suggestion of doing this or any extra option that one function 
 will execute to `initialize` this `variable` whenever any method is getting called.

Comment: Do you need intialize this variable each time the method is call? Or just one time on the first call?

Comment: If you want initialize the variable only on the first call, I think Lazy : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netstandard-2.0

Comment: Why do you want the *connection string* in the controller? Inject a database context or repository object instead that's configured in `Startup.cs`. If you want to select contexts based on a parameter, inject a factory method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can't inject the connection string when the class is created because you won't know which connection string you'll need until the method is called.

But the good news is that you're already using DI, which makes this easier.

Instead of injecting a connection string, inject a factory which returns the connection string you need.

That could be either an interface:

```
public interface IConnectionStringFactory
{
    string GetConnectionString();
}
```

or a delegate:

```
public delegate string GetConnectionStringFunction();
```

If there's some piece of information the method has that determines which connection string will get used then you can pass that to the factory:

```
public interface IConnectionStringFactory
{
    string GetConnectionString(Something whatever);
}
```

The logic for selecting a connection string is in the implementation of the factory.

The class that needs the connection string remains simple and testable because it doesn't contain logic for figuring out which connection string to use. It just depends on the factory:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IConnectionStringFactory _connectionStringFactory;

    public MyClass(IConnectionStringFactory connectionStringFactory)
    {
        _connectionStringFactory = connectionStringFactory;
    }

    public async Task<MyClass> GetDetails(int Id)
    { 
        var connectionString = _connectionStringFactory.GetConnectionString();
        con = new Connection(connectionString);
        //and after that other logic.....
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, it's probably undesirable in this case to update the class-level variable each time the method is called. If we do that then imagine what happens if the class is called concurrently for two different requests and each one uses a different connection string. One could overwrite the connection that another was just about to use.

Or, imagine if you update a class-level variable, but then another developer adds a new method but doesn't realize that they need to update it too. They just see the one that's there and use it.

So a benefit of this approach is that each time the method is called, there are no side effects to the class instance that could affect other calls to the same method.

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate for replying to me @Scott Hannen

Comment: I like your approach but again inside the method some piece of code needs to be written. The problem is it's an exiting app and there are lot of methods. Is there any alternate way without touching the inside code of methods

Comment: If each method call potentially needs a different connection string then I don't think there's any way around it. Or if there is it will be way more complicated then changing the code in the methods.
If the change is going to be the same in every method then you could put the new code to call the factory into a new method, and have every method call that one. It doesn't reduce the amount of work you do now, but if you ever have to change it again then that change would be limited to a single method.

Comment: Yes understood. Let me check for some other stuffs if not able to get through then definitely will be implementing as you suggested. Thanks again man